# can not send mail by port 25 but can with SSL on port 465

Tags: postfix

```
netstat -tunlp | grep :25
(No info could be read for "-p": geteuid()=1000 but you should be root.)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:25              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp6       0      0 :::25                   :::*                    LISTEN      -
```

i am having problem sending mails with postfix. I can send it by SSL and port 465 but not with port 25. When I use port 25 i can't get any error in /var/log/mail.log or mail.err

Port is opened:

```
telnet agadomarketing.com 25
Trying 84.255.253.186...
Connected to agadomarketing.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.agadomarketing.com ESMTP Postfix
```

when i send by roundcube mail i get this:

> Jul 15 10:06:07 ubuntu-server postfix/smtpd[9272]: lost connection
>   after UNKNOWN from localhost[127.0.0.1] Jul 15 10:06:07 ubuntu-server
>   postfix/smtpd[9272]: disconnect from localhost[127.0.0.1]

generally error

> SMTP Error (-1): Connection to server failed

EDIT:

```
my /etc/hosts

127.0.0.1      localhost
127.0.1.1      ubuntu-server.agadomarketing.com        ubuntu-server
```

what can be wrong? Is etc/hosts correct?

Comment: You can connect to your server on port 25, the telnet shows us that, and Postfix is listening.  What happens when you try to send a mail?  It probably gives your client an error message.

Comment: in roundcube i get SMTP Error (-1): Connection to server failed.

Comment: Can you, from the server, telnet out to a mail server on 25 just to make sure that there's nothing else in the chain that's blocking the SMTP traffic?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've typoed in a config file.  See what I get when I do:

```
[madhatta@risby iplayer]$ telnet agadomarketing.com 25
Trying 84.255.253.186...
Connected to agadomarketing.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mail.agadomatketing.com ESMTP Postfix
```

Note the incorrect spelling of the domain name in the ESMTP header.  If your server really does believe that it's the authoritative mail repository for agadomatketing.com, it'll probably refuse to accept mail for agadomarketing.com, because it'll regard that as foreign traffic and thus relaying.  When sending via SSL, you're probably also doing SMTP AUTH, and would therefore be allowed to relay.  Though who knows what it's doing with mail it then accepts for your real domain?

If this does turn out to be the correct explanation, **may I applaud you for not obscuring the domain name in your original question**.  That's a common enough practice on SF, but it's deeply annoying to those of us who'd like to help, as it blinds us to many channels of investigation.

Comment: Let me second that applause. It's so very much easier to help when you have the full data.

Comment: @MadHatter sorry domain is agadomarketing.com.  
I changed sudo hostname mail.agadomarketing.com but I still can not send mails in port 25. What must be my /etc/hots file maybe is here problem?

Comment: +1 for +1ing the applause.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely your Internet Service Provider is blocking outgoing connections on port 25. This is very common with residential cable and ADSL connections.

Comment: we have business conections and it works until 3 days ago. Now we changed domain and it sop working...

Comment: Did you actually ask your ISP? Maybe they changed something on the same day.